# show shortcode in externel php file

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

i'm using a social login plugin and i have created another php file ( mydomain.Com/wizard/index.php )

and i want to include the shortcode tat show the icons of social login to help users to register/login using social medias.

the steps are showed here

```
https://docs.oneall.com/plugins/guide/social-login-wordpress/#4
```

i tried this

```
<?php require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php'); ?>
<?php echo do_shortcode('[oa_social_login]'); ?>
<?php do_action('[oa_social_login]'); ?>
```

but nothing is showed however the shortcode [oa_social_login] is working in pages correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not include square brackets in the shortcode functions:

```
<?php require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php'); ?>
<?php echo do_shortcode('oa_social_login'); ?>
<?php do_action('oa_social_login'); ?>
```